# Synchronizing 3rd party Azure AD tenant directory user/group data with an application’s data store

Tags: azure, ldap, azure-ad-graph-api

As part of "new customer onboarding process", we are going to develop custom application using Azure AD Graph API for synchronizing 3rd party tenant active directory user and group data with in our application’s data store.

1. What azure container should be best fit to hold custom business logic above requirement?
2. What authentication is required to connect & query 3rd party tenant?
3. Azure AD Graph API or LDAP query which is efficient/best fit ?
4. How any user or and group data changes in 3rd party tenant active directory will be notified to my custom application in order to sync up our application’s data store? Is it possible in LDAP approach?

We are in investigation phase

Comment: You should use Microsoft Graph API instead of AAD Graph API. For sync you can use MS Graph API's change notifications. But you will need to make a scheduled full sync just in case you miss notifications etc. Also you don't use LDAP with AAD.

Comment: Some of my above queries(#1 , #2) are left unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What azure container should be best fit to hold custom business logic above requirement?

This is quite a broad question, and one I cannot answer definitely.
But Web Jobs or Durable Functions could work.

> What authentication is required to connect & query 3rd party tenant?

If this is like any tenant who starts using your app, then you'd register a multi-tenant app in your AAD and require application permissions to Read all users' basic/full info from Microsoft Graph API.
You then need to provide a functionality to the 3rd party tenant admin to consent to those permissions.
This means you'd need to redirect them to login to your app, at which time they'll be asked for permissions.
The topic of consent alone is a bit complex, the documentation is here though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/consent-framework.

Your app can then use Client Credential authentication in the background to get an access token for MS Graph API and do the sync / register for change notifications.

> Azure AD Graph API or LDAP query which is efficient/best fit ?

Neither, use Microsoft Graph API.

> How any user or and group data changes in 3rd party tenant active directory will be notified to my custom application in order to sync up our application’s data store?

You can get change notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0.
But you'll probably need to make a full sync as well so that all works in case you miss some updates.
The simplest solution is just a full sync that runs on a schedule.
It isn't fast or efficient but it is quite reliable.

Comment: Clarification required on #2 What authentication is required to connect & query 3rd party tenant? My azure app is going query third party azure active directory using microsoft graph api rest endpoints, if this the case what kind of authentication/permissions required from both my azure function and 3rd party azure AD to establish communication between them?

Comment: You would use OpenID Connect + OAuth 2 typically.

Comment: Could you explain OpenID Connect + OAuth 2 in simple terms & provide some working sample using OpenID Connect + OAuth 2?please

Comment: Any reason, why you are suggesting Azure durable function over azure function? any specific advantage it adds?

Comment: The capability to scale and run long running tasks.

Comment: Though I suppose you can run long running functions if you run it on an app service plan instead of a consumption plan :) But at that point you might as well use Webjobs.

Comment: what is the suggested frequency of full sync?

Comment: There really isn't one. It depends how stale can you allow the data get. For a lot of people max 24 hours old data is fine, for others it is not.

Comment: Thanks for above clarification & it make sense. To use graph api change notification about Azure AD resource, what i can expect in notification body, will it provide modified userid? to use the same in the query to modified data of user (or) if i have to execute delta query to get the updated user details what would details/token which will be used in query url?

Comment: Do we need to expose public(internet available) HTTPS endpoint to create a subscription and receive change notifications from Microsoft Graph? or there any other alternatives? please suggest. As our client wont allow their web api end points to be available over the internet?